# E: Unable to locate package python3-fpylll

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, package, apt, deb

Trying to install **Fpylll** package on **Ubuntu** as per the doc:

[LINK](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/21.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/python3-fpylll_0.5.2+ds1-3_amd64.deb.html)

```
Update the package index:

# sudo apt-get update

Install python3-fpylll deb package:

# sudo apt-get install python3-fpylll
```

**I receive a notification:**

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package python3-fpylll
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable universe repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-fpylll
```